WSO2 APIM 4.2.0 send the host to the backend
I need the apim host to reach the backend when I am consuming a service.
Is there a way to add a configuration line in deploymen.toml?
The problem I have is: when consuming the service I have in docker where I tell it show me the data it receives in the header when it goes through wso2 it shows me the IP of the endpoint configured in the API in the host , but when I consume the service without going through wso2, it shows me the host that I send it correctly.
Thanks for the support you can give me

Are you referring to the HOST header for this specific scenario or something else? Could you please elaborate more on your requirement that you are trying to achieve. As per your query, you want to pass the API Manager's HOST to the Backend? Or is it you want to bypass whatever the HOST header when going through the API Manager?

Yes, I want to pass the API Manager host header to the backend.

By default, what is the Host header you are receiving at the Backend server? And what is your API Manager Hostname configured? The Host header actually reflects the actual destination server's host value. Therefore, please use a custom header to pass any Host values that you need to the Backend. Also, you can use the X-Forwarded-Host header to send the API Manager Host name to the Backend server. Is your requirement is to configure the X-Forwarded-Host header?
